# Unable to get the FindNext property of the Range class

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, delete-row

I'm making an employee training database and I want to be able to remove all instances of an employee after they leave. Their employee number is in column F (because many employees have the same name, the number is easiest).

So I want to search for all instances of that employee number and delete the entire row. I was able to make it delete one instance of the employee number, but then it wouldn't find the next one. I added the `FindNext` command but got the error:

> Unable to get the `FindNext` property of the `Range` class.

Why would the `Find` be ok, but not the `FindNext`?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdDeleteA_Click()

'declare the variables

    Dim findvalue As Range
    Dim cDelete As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim cNum As Integer
'error statement

    On Error GoTo errHandler:

'check for values

    If Reg1.Value = "" Or Reg4.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is not data to delete"
        Exit Sub
    End If
'give the user a chance to change their mind

    cDelete = MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to delete this training", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Are you sure????")
    If cDelete = vbYes Then

'the next few paragraphs until "Loop While.." was recently added
'set the search range and find the row (2 layers)

    Dim rgF As Range
    Set rgF = Sheet2.Range("F:F")


        Set findvalue = rgF.Find(What:=Reg4, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)


        'If the ID doesn't exist, get out of there
        If findvalue Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "No one has that ID anymore"
            Exit Sub
        End If

       Do
        'delete the row that has the ID

        findvalue.EntireRow.Delete

        'find the next instance
        Set findvalue = rgF.FindNext(findvalue)
        Loop While Not findvalue Is Nothing

    End If

'clear the controls

    cNum = 9
    For x = 1 To cNum
        Me.Controls("Reg" & x).Value = ""
    Next

'run the filter

    AdvFilter
'add the values to the listbox
    lstLookUp.RowSource = ""
    lstLookUp.RowSource = "Staff_Filter"
'error block

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

errHandler::

    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & "The error number is:  " _
           & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
           "Please notify the administrator"

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102958/4539709

Comment: You can't `FindNext` if you've deleted `findValue` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through each cell in the range, just use a `Do...Loop While` loop and exit the loop once `findValue` is `Nothing`.

```
Dim rgF As Range
Set rgF = Sheet2.Columns("F")

Do
    Set findValue = rgF.Find(what:=Reg4, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not findValue Is Nothing Then findValue.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not findValue Is Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to `FIND()` would be to use something like:

```
    Dim rgF As Range
    Set rgF = Sheet2.Range("F:F")

    For Each cll In rgF
        Set c = .Find(Reg4, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If c Is NOT Nothing Then
            ' Do whatever
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: If you're going to loop through each individual cell though, it wouldn't make sense to use `Find` any longer.

Comment: Interesting. Would I be able to use this code to edit employee information for all rows that have the matching employee ID number?

Comment: For example. F is the column with the ID number


Dim rgF As Range
    Set rgF = Sheet2.Range("F:F")

    For Each cell In rgF
      Set c =  Find(What:=Me.Reg4.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, -3)  

        If c Is NOT Nothing Then

'update the values


c= Reg1.Value
c.Offset(0, 1) = Reg2.Value
c.Offset(0, 2) = Reg3.Value
'c.Offset(0, 3) = Reg4.Value skip ID#
c.Offset(0, 4) = Reg5.Value
        Next
    Next

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the fact that you are deleting *findvalue* but attempting to use it as the *After:=findvalue* argument with the FindNext call. Once the row containing *findvalue* has been deleted, it is no longer available for reference.

You can keep deleting the rows but subsequent calls need to be Range.Find, not Range.FindNext.

```
   Set findvalue = rgF.Find(What:=Reg4, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

   'if the ID doesn't exist, get out of there
   If findvalue Is Nothing Then
       Debug.Print "No one has that ID anymore"
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Do
       'delete the row that has the ID
        findvalue.EntireRow.Delete

        Set findvalue = rgF.Find(What:=Reg4, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Loop While Not findvalue Is Nothing
```

Alternately, collect all of the Find/FindNext ranges into a union and delete them all at once after they have been collected.

```
    Dim rgF As Range, allFound As Range, addr As String
    Set rgF = Sheet2.Range("F:F")

    Set findvalue = rgF.Find(What:=Reg4, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If findvalue Is Nothing Then
        'If the ID doesn't exist, get out of there
        Debug.Print "No one has that ID anymore"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'there is at least one row to delete
        'store original range address
        addr = findvalue.Address(0, 0)
        'seed the union oof ranges
        Set allFound = findvalue
        Do
            'collect into Union
            Set allFound = Union(findvalue, allFound)

            'find the next instance
            Set findvalue = rgF.FindNext(after:=findvalue)
        Loop Until findvalue.Address(0, 0) = addr

        'delete all row inthe union
        allFound.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```